# Magento custom pricing rule

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I need a custom pricing rule that can be used with fixed quantities. I need to apply discounts to certain groups of items in the cart. I think a custom salesrule would be the way to go but I need the collection of products in the cart instead of a single product. Any ideas?

*EDIT*

To clarify, I need to be able to have two particular items within a specified category have a discount applied. Let's call them product A and product B. The quantity of product A and product B must sum up to a specified number in the shopping cart rule, for example, 100 (quantity 50 for product A and quantity 50 for product B typically). This rule would need to apply to be applied to products/sets of products/the cart multiple times, e.g., product C and product D should have the discount applied if their quantities sum to 100.

Product A/B could be added to the cart again but as a quantity that does not qualify for the discount, i.e. a quantity < 100.

Answer (score 1):

Use "shopping cart price rules" under "Promotions"

Use a combination of "Conditions" and "Actions"

Use the "Conditions" to determine when the rule will start.

Use the "Actions" to determine which items to apply the rule to.

That will allow you to say something like "If customer has a blue jacket, red jacked, and orange jacket, discount the orange jacket 20%" or something like that.

Tip: Attributes can be used in actions and conditions. If you dont see the attribute there to select from, go to Catalog>Attributes>Manage Attributes, open the attribute you want to use (such as sku), and make sure its set to "Use for Promo Rule Conditions" "YES"

If your rule doesnt work, keeping playing with it. It has to be exact in order to work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The tip about using attributes is pretty helpful but I couldn't get the rules to work exactly how they should.